# "What we have done" in one word?

Tags: word-choice

I'm composing a 'Contents' slide for presentation, and I cannot come up with a concise word to describe "What we have done" in one word. What do people commonly use to describe that in the contents section?

PS. It would also be great to know one-word expressions of these sentences: "What we are going to do", "What we should do", "What we found".

---

The presentation is to explain the progress and future plan of our project. In this context, the "What we have done" section is meant to explain what we have done and what the outcomes are. I considered the term "Progress", but I thought it lacks implying the 'past' events. (It's like something we are still doing rather than we have done.)

The "We are going to do" section would present the objectives or action items to do in future, and I'm currently using the term "Future plan". I just wondered it's good enough to seem like natural.

Comment: What's the presentation about? The solution/one word might be found in the subject itself. Anyway, *executed* could fit the bill but it might not be suitable if the topic is mapping down DNA for instance. *Accomplished* and *achieved* could also work. "What we are going to do" could be covered by *aims* or *goals*.

Comment: I'm casting my vote to close this question because it lacks detail and research.  I'll be happy to retract once you've added the terms you discarded and explained why.

Comment: I added some details and my thoughts. :)

Comment: The meaning of "what we have done" is perfectly clear, that's not the problem here. What's the "presentation" and/or "project" about? For example, I might suggest *investigated* if the project is based on research work, but how do I know if it is appropriate or not to the situation? There are lots of words that could "fit" and represent "What we have done". You got to help users narrow down the choice.

Comment: A very common single word used to convey the idea of "what we have done" is _accomplishments_. Check its definitions in a dictionary to see whether it fits the situation that you are talking about.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The project is about fabricating a digital chip for accelerating some kind of scientific simulation. In the presentation, I meant to convey that we have surveyed some of our related work and derived design goals that we should accomplish.

Comment: @SvenYargs 'Accomplishments' could be a choice, but I thought it may give feel like it's about already finished work. Thank you for your recommendation. :)

Comment: The problem with "What we have done" is that it sounds like a lament. I would probably use "What we have done so far", if a better alternative could not be found.

Answer (score 2):

Single words for *What we have done* might be *Research* or *Trials*; perhaps *Tests* or *Experiments*. It might matter whether you’re reporting *everything* you’ve done, or only what was successful. Either way, why does it need to be a single word, please?

What exactly would be wrong with *What we have done*?

Very loosely you might use *Remaining* for *What we are going to*… or *… should do.* However, distinguishing between *What we are going to do* and *What we should do* in single words is almost certainly impossible.

*What we found* might become *Conclusions*

Answer (score 1):

In a presentation, "What we have done" is often titled ***Accomplishments***. Sometimes people use *Results*, but strictly speaking, results are the consequences of what was done, while accomplishments is understood to more broadly include the work that went into achieving the results. In a context of a long list of things to get done toward the final goal, such as the many, many steps that go into building an office building, the list might simply be titled *Completed*. The choice among these words is really about what kind of value judgement you are making.

- You worked hard and generated valuable results that you deserve praise for: **Accomplishments**. Typical in a business setting where you did some things that had a positive impact on the business.
- You did some research or experiments to figure something out and indeed, figured it out ("What we found out"): **Results** or **Conclusions**. Scientific papers have both sections, with Results being the most objective measurements possible and Conclusions being the interpretation of the results into some more meaningful concept. We gave 100 people a pill a day for a year. At the end of the year, 50 of them lost over 10% or more of their starting weight and 20 of them died. (Those are *results*.) The *conclusion* is that the pill is a powerful weight loss promoter but the health risks outweigh the benefits in all but the most morbidly obese patients.
- You are planning a wedding and got invitations picked out, printed, and mailed: **Completed**. This is more of a project management kind of report, showing how the small steps of the big project are being done on time and on budget (hopefully).

For your other phrases:

- "What we should do" -> **Recommendations** or **Future Research**
- "What we are going to do" -> **Next Steps** or **Proposal**

*Next steps* means you are committed to (and possibly have already started) doing the next things. *Proposal* or *proposed next steps* is what you want to do, but you are asking for permission and/or funding or something like that in order to be able to do it.

You could use **Plans** for "what we are going to do" but plans is more like what you are thinking you are going to do, it does not convey a strong commitment to actually doing it. You could use **Follow Up** if what you did was research and from what you have learned you see you now need to do more research and this is what you are going to do to answer the newly raised questions.

Side note: When I first read the title of the question, I thought of "What have we done?" as a somewhat rhetorical question about coming to terms with unintended consequences of an action. The people who created the atomic bomb, after seeing what it did to Japan, said to each other "What have we done?" I don't know a good word for that.

Answer (score 0):

What about **Accomplishments**? That implies you've achieved something though - so you'd have to be clear about the outcomes of tasks, for better or worse; otherwise, **Progress**? That suggests steps you have taken towards achieving a goal. In project management you'd would expect to deliver regular "progress report" to show tasks that have been completed and their outcomes and update stakeholders also update them on any ongoing activities so I don't see it being a problem in the context you describe. If you imagine your project is moving from Point A to Point B, your progress is where you are right now and everything you've done before it to get you to that point.

For your other terms, how about:

"What we are going to do": **Plans** or **Tasks**

"What we should do": I'm not clear on what this is meant to describe. Things you would have done differently, or additional tasks?

"What we found": **Findings**, **Results**, or **Conclusions**